# grouping and conditional selection of duplicates in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, grouping

I select the rows that have duplicates and their duplicates from a dataframe.
 An example of the resulting dataframe can be this

```
df <- data.frame(ID = seq(1,10), A = rep(0,10), B = rep(seq(1,2),5), C = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5)))
df$A[c(1,3,10)]<-1
```

From this df I want

1) to create a new column where the different groups of duplicates are indexed (e.g. (A,B,A...) or (1.1,2.1,1.2...)

2) Remove/Select all the duplicated rows without removing the rows where A!=0
In the example I should keep rows with ID 1,2,3,7,10

I have tried

```
subset(df, !duplicated(df[c(3,4)]) | df$A==1)
```

but this keeps more rows (ID =6) because of the sorting.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: A subset of this dataframe where I want non duplicated rows based on columns B and C but I do not want to remove rows with df$A==1.

Comment: so just `df[!(duplicated(df[c('B', 'C')]) & df$A != 1),]`